# Manifold with totally geodesic boundary is spin if and only if its double is spin

Tags: riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with totally geodesic boundary $\partial M$. Let $(DM,Dg)$ be the double of $(M,g)$ obtained by reflection of across $\partial M$. I'm looking for a reference for the following fact:

$(M,g)$ is spin if and only if $(DM,Dg)$ is spin.

Thank you very much!